# RAM usage issue in window server with MongoDB and C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, c#-4.0

I have Mongo database, size of 30 GB.
In windows server i limited space of RAM - 10GB
Using MongoDb C# driver i am trying to execute

```
query = (from da in collection.AsQueryable<FullTune>()
where da.Letter.Equals(Letter.ToUpper()) && da.Styles.Equals(Style)
select da).OrderBy(a => a.Title).Take(50).ToList();
```

Its eating RAM of 10GB and hang server, same query using Mongo console, its working fine, without RAM usage.

How can this performance issue solved.

Comment: Try running the query generated by that Linq code in a Data Reader, and see if you still get that much memory hogging. If it doesn't, then the problem is in getting all that data translated into .NET objects. You can then refine your logic to make it more lightweight.

Comment: What's "eating 10GB" of RAM? On your client or on the server? What query are you running from the console? I've used this: http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1833 trick to get the query that has been generated by the LINQ statements to compare it to those I would hand-write.

Comment: What do you intend `Letter.ToUpper()` to represent? Have you declared a `string` variable named `Letter`?

Comment: Eating 10GB of RAM, its hanging cpu. if i use query in Mongo for same condition, its working without RAM usage, but in C# object, its creating issue.

Comment: 10GB of RAM on the client (the C# application)?

Comment: Try moving the "order by" into the `from` as `orderby da.Title`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the [LINQ provider](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/) doesn't support `.Equals()` and it may need to execute it in memory.

Also as a style guideline I wouldn't usually mix LINQ query syntax with LINQ extension method style as you have done and prefer to be consistent.

In any case I would suggest changing your query to the following:

```
result = collection.AsQueryable<FullTune>()
    .Where(ft => ft.Letter == Letter.ToUpper() && ft.Styles == Style)
    .OrderBy(ft => ft.Title)
    .Take(50);
```